# Set OnLongPressed event on Scaffold Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to set the OnLongPressed and OnPressed or OnTap events on a Scaffold using flutter?

Regards,

Comment: The Scaffold is the whole page. Do you want to set those events in the whole Scaffold or just in a part of it?

Comment: I wanna set it in just part of that
I have a Card that contains an Scaffold, I need the event there, let me explain a little bit
I have a GridView that has cards, each card should have that event.

Comment: Wrap your Card in a GestureDetector Widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GestureDetector` - it has many parameters, e.g. `onTap`, `onLongPress`, etc.